# Reproducibility in scientific computing

Tags: linux, logging, version-control, scientific-computing

A common workflow in scientific computing is to first write code (perhaps a simulation), run it and analyse its results, then make modifications based on what the previous round of results show.  This cycle may go round tens, possibly even hundreds of times before the project is finished.

A key problem of this development cycle is one of reproducibility.  As I have gone through this cycle, I will have produced results, graphs, and various other output.  I want to be able to take any graph (from yesterday, last week, month, or longer) and **reliably** reconstruct the code and environment which were used to produce this.  How can I solve this problem?  The "obvious" solution appears to be one of organisation and recording everything, however this has the potential to create much additional work.  I'm interested in the balance of achieving this without handicapping productivity.

Comment: The question could be rephrased to be more problem-oriented, along the lines of "how can I efficiently and **reliably** record my simulation code and inputs?" Conceivably there may be completely different approaches that address this problem.  Would this be a better fit for the SO format?

Comment: Since the very heavy editing this question has become a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734157/reproducibility-in-scientific-programming  It's still of doubtful topicality too.

Comment: Have you already seen http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/2525/how-do-i-make-sure-that-the-results-of-my-simulations-and-the-results-in-my-pape/2526 and http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/1617/scientific-workflow-management-system/1874#1874 ?

Comment: I hadn't seen those before.  They are very close to what I'm after, and there are a number of high-quality suggestions to try out.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

http://ipython.org/notebook.html
for people who want to share reproducible research.

http://jupyter.org/
Not just python, there are many languages supported.

Recently, i was experimenting with julia language,
[this is](http://quant-econ.net/jl/getting_started.html) one of the advised tutorials.
It's using IJulia which is based on IPython, very nice intro.

Comment: IPython notebook and Jupyter likely have a place in all this, but I don't think it directly addresses the reproducibility issue.  If I take a .ipynb notebook today, leave it for five years and re-run it, it almost certainly will not work.  I can put it in a virtualenv and print out `pip freeze` to capture all of the python package versions, but there will still be unrecorded dependencies on the non-python libraries on my current system.  I can record these manually, but this is error-prone and tedious.  That said, the notebook format does a great job of coupling the code and the output.